# how to package dojo for javascript maven tools?

Tags: javascript, maven, dojo, js-amd

I am looking for the best packaging approach for a RIA written in java/javascript, and struggling with the javascript part.
I have found the JS RIA maven archetype at http://mojo.codehaus.org/javascript-maven-tools/javascript-ria-archetype/index.html
However my application uses dojo instead of jquery. Question is how to package dojo to make it available as a dependency?
I was trying this:

1. mvn install:install-file   -DgroupId=org.dojotoolkit   -DartifactId=dojo   -Dversion=dojo-1.9.0 -Dpackaging=zip  -Dfile=/home/mag/.m2/repository/org/dojotoolkit/dojo/1.9.0/dojo-1.9.0.zip   -DgeneratePom   -DcreateChecksum

   the version number is that weird because I was trying to match the directory structure in target to the one I see for jquery
2. adding dependency to this and some unpacking to pom.xml:

   ```
   <!--project/dependencies -->
               <dependency>
                   <groupId>org.dojotoolkit</groupId>
                   <artifactId>dojo</artifactId>
                   <version>dojo-1.9.0</version>
                   <type>zip</type>
               </dependency>

   <!--project/build/plugins -->
                   <plugin>
                     <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                     <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                     <executions>
                       <execution>
                         <id>unpackDojo</id>
                         <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                         <goals>
                           <goal>unpack</goal>
                         </goals>
                         <configuration>
                           <artifactItems>
                             <artifactItem>
                               <groupId>org.dojotoolkit</groupId>
                               <artifactId>dojo</artifactId>
                               <classifier>sources</classifier>
                               <version>${dojo.version}</version>
                               <type>zip</type>
                               <outputDirectory>target/classes/js/org/dojotoolkit/
                               </outputDirectory>
                             </artifactItem>
                           </artifactItems>
                         </configuration>
                       </execution>
                     </executions>
                   </plugin>
   ```
3. inserting "dojo/query" in a javascript source as AMD:

   ```
   + define( ["jquery","dojo/query"], function($,query) {
   - define( ["jquery"], function($) {
   ```

   in the beginning of src/main/js/HelloWorld/HelloWorldController.js

The target now looks like this:

```
    target/classes/js/org/dojotoolkit/dojo-1.9.0/dojo-dojo-1.9.0/query.js
    target/classes/js/org/codehaus/mojo/jquery-amd/1.7.1-alpha-1/jquery-amd-1.7.1-alpha-1.js
```

and I get this:

[ERROR] Dependency not found: dojo/query in file: [...]/src/main/js/HelloWorld/HelloWorldController.js

I have no clue on how AMDing "jquery" leads to finding target/classes/js/org/codehaus/mojo/jquery-amd/1.7.1-alpha-1/jquery-amd-1.7.1-alpha-1.js after extensive research for any hint in my ~/.m2 and target directories.
Hence I have no idea how to prepare dojo to make "dojo/anything" bring in the needed dependency.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Do you really have to use a archetype? I use Dojo, jQuery and quite a few other JS libraries in my project and build it all using maven. I wrote briefly about it on my blog [here](http://bharathwrites.in/posts/build-dojo-1819-with-maven/). Maybe if you break the problems you are having into smaller pieces it will be easier to help